# How to parse a XML returns from a GET (in Android)

Tags: android, parsing, dom

```
url = new URL(url_str);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(stream);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
Node node = doc.getElementsByTagName("baseName").item(0);
Log.d(TAG,">>>>"+node.getNodeValue());
```

When i try the "url_str" on web browser it gives me the following XML.

```
<files>
<file>
<fileId>441190</fileId>
<license>4</license>
<path>images</path>
<originalSource>
http://www.flickr.com/photos/stevendepolo/5165129565/sizes/m/
</originalSource>
<owner>Steven Depolo</owner>
<baseName>photo_5165129565_0ca9b101b0_t.jpg</baseName>
</file>
</files>
```

But for my output of "node.getNodeValue()" it returns null. But I need to get the string between baseName tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try node.getTextContent(); instead of node.getNodeValue() this solved me most of the problems i had related to node value. sometimes the node value is not set instead the value is set to the text content.

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked another fields? Does it returns the value for them? 
Please call `getNodeType()` on your node, what it returns? 
Consider using XPath instead.